# what does "out of choice" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "out of choice" mean in this article?
Does it mean, he didn't have other choices?

https://www.quora.com/Would-becoming-homeless-be-a-good-strategy-to-cut-costs-1/answer/Kurt-Varner

> I recently concluded a 4 month adventure of living from my car in
>   Silicon Valley. Don't listen to the naysayers. It can be done, and it
>   will save you a ton of money. I did this **out of choice**, also while
>   bootstrapping my startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case "out of" means **because of**, he's saying his lifestyle is the result of a choice. The phrase "out of" has [many meanings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/out-of) and you see it used in a lot of different contexts. The link provided lists the various ways "out of" can be used, and includes the **because of** meaning I mentioned.